# Update the document.referrer via history.pushState()

Tags: html, pushstate

I'm using pushStates in my ajax-app to navigate from one "page" to another. Now, I'd like to see from what page I was coming from. But `document.referrer` always returns `""`. Or, when I open my app from another page (where it is linked), I got the URL from that other page.

Shouldn't these lines...

`history.pushState({}, "Some title", "/some/valid/url/1");`

`history.pushState({}, "Some title", "/some/valid/url/2");`

...produce a referrer like this:

`http://somedomain.com/some/valid/url/1`

?

Or in other words: Is there any way to set the `document.referrer` accordingly, or at least reset it to `""`?

Note: I'm looking for solutions without caching the previous URL in some variable. I need something that really changes the `document.referrer`, because I cannot change the scripts that rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**: use `window.location` instead of `history.pushState`

**Longer Answer**:

`document.referrer` according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer): *"The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark)"*

Directly manipulating the `history` state will not be treated as following a link. You can simulate a link click by update `window.location` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)) which will also update the history automatically.

For example, load a tab with `https://github.com/kanaka/mal/`. Then type the following one line at a time (otherwise they are all run in a single javascript execution context and only the last location update applies)

```
console.log(history.length)     // 2
console.log(document.referrer)  // ""
window.location = "/kanaka/mal/tree/master/ada"
console.log(history.length)     // 3
console.log(document.referrer)  // "https://github.com/kanaka/mal"
window.location = "/kanaka/mal/tree/master/python"
console.log(history.length)     // 4
console.log(document.referrer)  // "https://github.com/kanaka/mal/tree/master/ada"
```

Comment: Changing `window.location` reloads the page. Is there a way to do this without reloading the page?